# Sum of Cantor Sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let C denote the usual cantor set(which is obtained from the interval [0,1]).Then what is the sum of three such cantor sets i.e. what is C+C+C=?

Answer (score 5):

Well, $C+C=[0,2],$ so it follows readily that $C+C+C=[0,3],$ by noting that $$[0,3]=[0,2]+\{0,1\}\subseteq[0,2]+C=C+C+C\subseteq[0,3].$$

As a hint for how to prove the first result, you should first prove that $\frac12C+\frac12C=[0,1],$ using the fact that the elements of $C$ are those that can be expressed as sums $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{t_k}{3^k},$$ where each $t_k\in\{0,2\}.$ On the other hand, every number in $[0,1]$ can be expressed as such a sum where $t_k\in\{0,1,2\}$.

---

**Added**: To prove the first result, we make use of a few properties of set addition and scalar multiplication, which we define for $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ and $X,Y\subseteq\Bbb R$ by

$$X+Y:=\{x+y:x\in X,y\in Y\}$$ and $$\alpha X:=\{\alpha x:x\in X\}.$$

In particular, we have the following:

- For any $D,E\subseteq\Bbb R$ and any $\alpha\in\Bbb R,$ we have $\alpha D+\alpha E=\alpha(D+E).$
- For any $B,F\subseteq R$ and any *non-zero* $\alpha\in\Bbb R,$ we have $\alpha B=\alpha F$ if and only if $B=F.$
- For any $D,E,F\subseteq\Bbb R$ and any *non-zero* $\alpha\in\Bbb R,$ we have $\alpha D+\alpha E=\alpha F$ if and only if $D+E=F.$

The third property follows directly from the first two. (Do you see how?) Let me prove the first one. (I leave the proof of the second to you.)

> On the one hand, suppose that $x\in\alpha D+\alpha E,$ meaning that $x=y+z$ for some $y\in\alpha D$ and some $z\in\alpha E.$ But then $y=\alpha s$ for some $s\in D$ and $z=\alpha t$ for some $t\in E.$ Then $s+t\in D+E$ and $x=y+z=\alpha s+\alpha t=\alpha(s+t),$ so $x\in\alpha(D+E).$ Since this holds for all $x\in\alpha D+\alpha E,$ then $\alpha D+\alpha E\subseteq\alpha(D+E).$
>
> On the other hand, suppose that $x\in\alpha(D+E).$ Then $x=\alpha y$ for some $y\in D+E,$ so $y=s+t$ for some $s\in D$ and some $t\in E,$ so $\alpha s\in\alpha D$ and $\alpha t\in\alpha E,$ and $x=\alpha y=\alpha(s+t)=\alpha s+\alpha t,$ so $x\in\alpha D+\alpha E.$ Since this holds for all $x\in\alpha(D+E),$ then $\alpha D+\alpha E\supseteq\alpha(D+E).$

Hence, if we can show that $\frac12C+\frac12C=[0,1],$ then since $[0,1]=\frac12[0,2],$ it follows by the third property that $C+C=[0,2],$ as desired.

Comment: Here the problem is C+C=[0,2] and 1/2*C+1/2*C=[0,1] but still C is not equal to 1/2C+1/2C as simply can be seen from the fact that C is a measure zero set while the set [0,1] is not.Actually these are set sums..so you can't split the elements of the set in two parts

Comment: For example let A={0,2}.here the set sum A+A={0,2,4}.but if split the elements of A into two parts like 2=1+1 ,rearrange and then take the sum then you will get elements like 1 in the sum-set which is not true..@Cameron

Comment: Ah, but I'm not claiming that $C=\frac12C+\frac12C.$ Rather, I'm using the fact that for real subsets $D,E,F$ and reals $\alpha,$ we have $\alpha D+\alpha E=\alpha(D+E).$ Hence, for $\alpha\ne0,$ we have $\alpha D+\alpha E=\alpha F$ if and only if $D+E=F.$ So, since $\frac12C+\frac12C=[0,1]=\frac12[0,2],$ then we have $C+C=[0,2].$

Comment: Your example $A=\{0,2\}$ actually demonstrates this nicely. $\frac12A=\{0,1\},$ so that $\frac12A+\frac12A=\{0,1,2\},$ but also $\frac12(A+A)=\{0,1,2\}.$ Anyhow, I will expand my answer to make clearer what I intend, here.